# Java Regular Expression Matcher not returning group of 2 consecutive digits when ORing with single digit group

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that extracts all consecutive digits from a string (including single digit)

Below regular expression is not able to extract 2 consecutive digits.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    print(checkRegex("2G18R"));
}
private static void print(String arr []) {
    for(String s : arr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
}
private static String [] checkRegex(String str) {
    System.out.println("original string " + str);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d{4})|(\\d{3})|(\\d{2})|(\\d+).*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        return new String [] {
            matcher.group(1),
            matcher.group(2),
            matcher.group(3),
            matcher.group(4)
        };
     }
     return new String [] {};
}
```

Expected output is that matcher.group(3) should return 18.
But it is returning null.

Overall expected output is [2, 18]

Comment: The first matched substring is `2` having one digit. What are you trying to achieve? what is the overall expected output? `[2, 18]` ?

Comment: “I am trying to create a regular expression that extracts all consecutive digits from a string (including single digit)” The pattern `"\\d{1,4}"` is all you need to do this.  You are literally looking for a sequence of 1–4 digits.  There is no need to make it more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if you just want the array of numbers or want to use regular expressions.  Here is an alternative to matching.  Just use split.

```
String[] array = {
        "2G18R","2sls2l2222l1l1","ksksks2232ksksk2k2k22k222k2k9282"
};
```

- Here, split will split the string on any length of nonDigits `\\D+`
- if all your strings start with digits, then you won't need the conditional copy as that just copies the array and skips the first cell if the string doesn't start with a digit.

```
for (String str : array) {
    String[] numbers = str.split("\\D+");
    if (numbers.length > 0 && numbers[0].isBlank()) {
        numbers = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, 1, numbers.length);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

You could also just take a stream approach and filter out the offending string.

```
for (String str : array) {
    String[] numbers = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))
            .filter(s -> !s.isBlank()).toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

both print the following

```
[2, 18]
[2, 2, 2222, 1, 1]
[2232, 2, 2, 22, 222, 2, 9282]
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `".*(\\d{4})|(\\d{3})|(\\d{2})|(\\d+).*"` would match something like `"abc1234|567|89|0efg"`

I suppose you need a pattern like this: `"(\\d{1,4})"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkRegex("2G18R");
    checkRegex("2G18R15559X9871C1");
}

private static void checkRegex(String str) {
    System.out.println("original string " + str);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
}
```

And output:

```
original string 2G18R
Result: [2, 18]
original string 2G18R15559X9871C1
Result: [2, 18, 15559, 9871, 1]
```